# ¿Cómo puedo encender un objeto que está apagado al iniciar el juego en Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity

Traigo ahorita un problema, ya que tengo un objeto apagado en mi escena, y cuando inicio el juego me gustaría que se encendiera, nada mas no lo logro con el `SetActive`, me podrían ayudar a cómo hacerlo mediante código en c#.. Por favor.. Gracias:

Dejo aquí mi código

```
public class EstorbosCubos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubeGO;

    void EncenderCubo()
    {
        cubeGO.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    void InicioComponentes()
    {
        cubeGO = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    }

    void Start()
    {
        InicioComponentes();
        EncenderCubo();
    }
}
```

Comment: preguntas: Que objeto tiene el `EstorbosCubos` ? el objeto `Cube` esta dentro de la jerarquia de esos objetos? ten en cuenta que `find` busca hacia abajo en la jerarquia, si `Cube` esta fuera de esta, o es superior, no encontraras el objeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el objeto cubo está apagado, no se ejecutan sus métodos Awake, Start, Update, ...

Una opción sencilla que puedes utilizar es crear un GameObject vacío como gestor del juego (Game Manager) y agregarle un script con una referencia a los cubos que quieras encender.

Algo así:

```
public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject cubeGO;

void EncenderCubo()
{
    cubeGO.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}

void Start()
{
    EncenderCubo();
} }
```

Si tienes que activar y desactivar varios objetos simultáneamente puedes cambiar el tipo de objeto por un array o lista, y activarlos o desactivarlos todos o siguiendo la lógica que le quieras dar.

Por supuesto el GameManager debe estar activado al inicio para que funcione. Este objeto se suele utilizar para mantener los datos del juego, como las puntuaciones, olas de enemigos, tiempo, ...

**EDIT:** Por supuesto, el enlace debes hacerlo en el editor, puesto que el método Find que tu utilizas no detecta los GameObject que están apagados.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo mucho!!!

Answer (score 0):

soy nuevo por aquí, mil disculpas pero no entiendo la respuesta de José Delgado... espero no lo tomes a mal. He encontrado otra manera de hacerlo te comparto mi idea:
primero debemos crear un objeto y asignarle el siguiente código:

public GameObject sentim; // asignamos un GameObject publico

```
void Start()
{
    sentim.gameObject.SetActive(false); // en el start le indicamos que empiece apagado               
}

void Update() // en el Update creamos una condición lógica IF por ejemplo
{
    if (GameObject.Find("Cube")) // lo comparo con otro objeto en la escena y si es true
    {
        sentim.gameObject.SetActive(true);// enciendo el objeto

    }
    }
```

}

La comparación es solo una idea porque incluso puedes poner para que el objeto se active presionando una tecla o incluso después de un tiempo o condición con while.

en el espacio del GameObject publico arrastramos y colocamos el objeto que queremos que aparezca o desaparezca.
Bueno eso es todo y espero haber sido de ayuda, si no me entiendes puedes escribir para volver a explicar mas detalladamente, pero al parecer si dominas bastante bien el tema.

Un abrazo a todos.